# RegEx help to remove noise words or stop words from string

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I want to remove all noise tags from input tags (a string)
The tags are separated by comma. If a noise word is part of a big tag, it will remain.

This is what I have but not working:

```
string input_string = "This,sure,about,all of our, all, values";
string stopWords = "this|is|about|after|all|also";
stopWords = string.Format(@"\s?\b(?:{0})\b\s?", stopWords);
string tags = Regex.Replace(input_string, stopWords, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This is what I want from above input: 
  ",sure,,all of our,,values"

These words "This", "about", "all" will be replaced with "" since they are noise words.
But "all of our" will remain even if it has the noise word "all" in it.
This is because comma is the tag boundary

Anyone can give me a helping hand?

I had an alternate solution that puts the noise words into a dictionary and then search each word in input string. But I prefer RegEx approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var input = "This,sure,about,all of our, all, values";
        var stopWords = new Regex("^(this|is|about|after|all|also)$");
        var result = String.Join(",", input.Split(',').
            Where(x => !stopWords.IsMatch(x.Trim())));
```

Comment: how will the delegate perform? Replace() will be faster than doing with a delegate, not?

Comment: Probably. But "premature optimization is the root of all evil". And optimized code tends to be cryptic.

Comment: This works. Also I have more control with each tag I process through delegate. Though it may not perform optimally. But OK, I will have 5-7 tags on avg.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
stopWords = string.Format(@"(?<=^|,)\s*(?:{0})\s*(?=$|,)", stopWords);
```

This uses lookbehind `(?<=)` to determine a preceding , or start of string and lookahead `(?=)` to determine a trailing ,.  I've also dropped the word boundry `\b` code because its not needed and replaced your optional whitespace `\s?` with `\s*` to match 0 or more whitespaces.

You could change the * back to a ? if you really do mean at most one space.

Comment: user can enter any number of spaces anywhere in the string. If your solution works, it will be cool. Trying to test...

Comment: I tried stopWords = string.Format(@"(?<=^|,)\s*(?:{0})\s*(?=$|,)", stopWords); but it doesn't work

Comment: Really confused as to why this didn't work for you I ran `This,sure,about,all of our, all, values` through expresso with this and got `,sure,,all of our,, values`

Answer (score 0):

I don't like using Regex for processing tasks so I will offer an alternative solution and you can decide if you want to use it or not.

```
string[] inputWords = input_string.Split(',');
string tags = "";

foreach(string s in inputWords)
{
   if(!storWords.Contains(s.ToLowerInvariant()))
      tags += s + ",";
}

tags = tags.TrimEnd(',');

//tags = "sure,all of our,values"
```

Comment: I already have similar solution working. Not interested in this.

Comment: @Projapati, If you do not want to use then that is fine. But I fail to see why you want to change to a Regex solution (which you cannot even get to work) when you have a working solution already? Do you somehow think Regex is magic? Do you not think that behind the scenes Regex also has to do something similar?