# Stopwords removing from string

Tags: c#, string, stop-words

I am trying to remove the stopwords from string but the problem is it is removing the characters from the single words if it is appearing again in the string. 

For example the original string is:
"*this movie good."*
the resulted string is:
"***this movie good.***". works fine.but

If the string is: "**this movie is good.**" 

then resulted string will be: "***th movie good.***"

 As ***is***  repeating in this string so it is exempted in the result. 

Another string:
 "***this game is fantastic. So, I watched and played a lot.***"

result: "***gme  fntstic. So,  wtched  plyed  lot.***"

As **a** repeated in this string thus resulted string show all words exempting **a**.

I am sing this code:

```
List<string> stopWordsList = new List<string>();
stopWordsList = stopWordsFilter();//funtion returning the list of stop words taking from file.
        string propertyValue = "this game is fantastic. So, I watched and played a lot.";
        foreach (string word1 in propertyValue.Split(' '))
        {

            foreach ( var word in stopWordsList)
            {
                if (word.Equals(word1) && word.Length == word1.Length)
                {
                    propertyValue = propertyValue.Replace(word, "");
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(propertyValue);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx help to remove noise words or stop words from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813377/regex-help-to-remove-noise-words-or-stop-words-from-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you replace the stop-word with `String.Empty`. `String.Replace` doesn't care about *words* but substrings.

You could use this approach:

```
string propertyValue = "this game is fantastic. So, I watched and played a lot.";
var words = propertyValue.Split();
var newWords = words.Except(stopWordsFilter);
propertyValue = string.Join(" ", newWords);
```

If you want to ignore the case, so omit also `"Is"`:

```
var newWords = words.Except(stopWordsFilter, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It would be much better to use other delimiters as well.

`var words = propertyValue.Split(new char[]{' ', ',', ';', '.' })`

Answer (score 1):

I propose here a solution that uses linq:

```
    string result = propertyValue.Split(' ')
        .Where(s => !stopWordsList.Contains(s))
        .Aggregate((current, next) => current + " " + next);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```